# Does package-install do byte-compilation?

Tags: package, byte-compilation

When installing a package from the package menu, can/will `package-install` do automatic byte compilation of the installed package files? Or is this something the user must do manually himself afterwards?

For example, I have installed `auctex` from the package menu, but there are no `*.elc` files in my `~/.emacs.d/elpa/auctex-11.89.5` directory. Also I see from the [source of `package.el`](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/emacs.git/tree/lisp/emacs-lisp/package.el) that there is a function `package--compile` at line 942 (so that should indicate that it can byte-compile)

There is no mention of byte-compilation [in the Manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Package-Installation.html#Package-Installation) as far as I can see.

I am also wondering that I might have deleted the `*.elc` files myself and forgotten about it.

Comment: I didn't read the `package.el` code, but my understanding was that it would compile all ELisp code except for some special files (typically, the autoloads and iirc one can also put a special comment in lisp files to prevent batch byte-compilation, this would be in the "Local Variables" section, `no-byte-compile: t`.

Comment: If you think the manual needs improvement (e.g. it should mention byte-compiling), please consider filing a bug report: `M-x report-emacs-bug`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`package-install` does byte-compile the files, yes.  Not sure how/why your auctex install doesn't have any .elc files, tho.  Maybe a bug, or a pilot error.